# Map on 2 columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
        Col1           Col2
0        A              PY
1        B              PA
2        C              PB
3        B              PB
```

and this series:

```
                            Value
   Col1       Col2     
    A          PY             20
    B          PB             30
```

I would like to do a mapping,  if the series has one index(ex Col1 only) its pretty straightforward with:

```
  df['Value'] = df['Col1'].map(s)
```

How can I do mapping based on 2 indexes/columns ?

Thanks !

Comment: And what is the result you want to obtain with that mapping?

Comment: I get error related to index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can merge them on the common columns (columns with the same names):

```
In [28]: d1
Out[28]:
  Col1 Col2
0    A   PY
1    B   PA
2    C   PB
3    B   PB

In [29]: d2
Out[29]:
           Value
Col1 Col2
A    PY       20
B    PB       30

In [30]: d1.merge(d2.reset_index())
Out[30]:
  Col1 Col2  Value
0    A   PY     20
1    B   PB     30
```

or using left outer join:

```
In [33]: d1.merge(d2.reset_index(), how='left')
Out[33]:
  Col1 Col2  Value
0    A   PY   20.0
1    B   PA    NaN
2    C   PB    NaN
3    B   PB   30.0
```

same solution will work also for `d2` as Series:

```
In [31]: s
Out[31]:
Col1  Col2
A     PY      20
B     PB      30
Name: Value, dtype: int64

In [32]: d1.merge(s.reset_index())
Out[32]:
  Col1 Col2  Value
0    A   PY     20
1    B   PB     30
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [5]: d1
Out[5]:

   col1 col2
0    A   PY 
1    B   PA
2    C   PB
3    D   PB

In [7]: d2
Out[7]:

col1 col2  val
A   PY   20
B   PB   30
```

you can use either merge:

```
 In [8]: d1.merge(d2.reset_index())
 Out[8]:
    col1 col2   val
 0    A   PY    20
```

Or:

```
In [9]: result = pd.concat([d1, d2], axis=1)

In [10]: result
Out[10]:
   col1 col2 col1 col2   val
  0    A   PY    A   PY  20.0
  1    B   PA    B   PB  30.0
  2    C   PB  NaN  NaN   NaN
  3    D   PB  NaN  NaN   NaN
```