# Pandas Series transformation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Series that looks like this: (multiple indexes done from a groupby)

```
              Value
Col1 Col2
 A    PY       20
      PB       30
 B    PY       10
      PB       50
```

I would like to make it looks like this:

```
           Value
Col1 Col2
 A    PY       20
 A    PB       30
 B    PY       10   
 B    PB       50
```

Any suggestion on how to make it work ?

Thanks for help

EDIT: The twisted Problem:

I want to add the column 'Value' to the a dataframe that has the series' indexes as columns. When I merge this series with my original data frame, I'm getting nan's on a column called id.

Comment: Maybe also show us the *original* before the groupby.

Comment: this is the result of the groupby that I've saved in a serie

Comment: `how to make it work?` what does it refer to here? What is the actual problem. I dont think representation lead to any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the representation of data for the sake of better look. `MultiIndex` contains all values in first level, nothing there is missing.

EDIT:

I think there is some problem with data, because previous answer working really nice.

Another simplier solution with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
print (df1)
  Col1 Col2
0    A   PY
1    B   PA
2    C   PB
3    B   PB

print (df2)
           Value
Col1 Col2       
A    PY       20
     PB       30
B    PY       10
     PB       50

df = df1.join(df2, on=['Col1','Col2'])
print (df)
  Col1 Col2  Value
0    A   PY   20.0
1    B   PA    NaN
2    C   PB    NaN
3    B   PB   50.0
```

EDIT:

For convert `Series` to one column `DataFrame` use [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) function:

```
df2 = ser.to_frame('Value')
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988650/map-on-2-columns-pandas, when I merge I find out after that some indexes went NAN

Comment: Sorry I have a column called id that had nans

Comment: Can you eplain your problem more?

Comment: @hdatas so you think the index representation in causing the problem? Then your understanding is not strong.

Comment: I did a groupby based on 2 columns and did the count on a third column and saved it in a serie, I wanted to add a new column into the starting df with the results from the serie

Comment: I can do this easily with a groupby with 1 column but with 2 the map function gives an error

Comment: Can you edit your question wih your problem? Because if MultiIndex, `map` cannot be used, need `join` or `merge`

Comment: @jezrael what should I do if the df2 is a serie? should I just convert it to dataframe ? btw I 've edited my question

Comment: then need `df2 = s.to_frame('Value')`

Comment: ok I'll try it :)

Comment: @hdatas - I add it to answer ;)

Comment: @jezrael a bit of delay but all worked thanks man ;)